# select distinct on model and iterate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm having issues getting a distinct record from my DB for one of my models.

I'm using EF to select and return the table contents to the model type which I then iterate over, the below code works just fine:

```
IQueryable<StudentRecord> students = _dbaccess.GetAllStudents();
```

Where `_dbaccess` is a local instance of an interface to DB context and `GetAllStudents` returns all items of that model from the DB context itself.

---

```
foreach (StudentRecord student in students)
{
    if (student.Name == "something")
    {
    }
}
```

---

The issue arises when I try to use LINQ to select distinct students:

---

```
IQueryable<StudentRecord> students = 
                              _dbaccess.GetAllStudents().Select(x => x.StudentID).Distinct();
```

---

Because of the way my loop is structured I need to access various members of my model, but I can't use LINQ when my enumeration variable is of the type of `StudentRecord` (it works with a string but that then means I cant access the model members in my loop).

Is there an easy way to implement this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: var studentsCustom = _dbaccess.GetAllStudents().Select(x => x.StudentID).Distinct();   you can loop through this

Comment: use `GroupBy` and enumerate over the result

Comment: You need to group by. Suppose you have two students with different names but same StudentID. You made Distinct on StudentID - how do you think it should choose between those two names?